# Why isn't the remove() working in python

Tags: python

I am using a for loop to loop through a 2D list and removing everything, but only one set of the duplicates get removed:

```
>>> one = [['red', 'rfg', 'erg', '234', '23423434234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
    ['red', 'gertus', 'gengie', '234', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
    ['red', 'sdf', 'sdf', '23', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
    ['red', 'rfg', 'erg', '234', '23423434234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
    ['red', 'gertus', 'gengie', '234', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
    ['red', 'sdf', 'sdf', '23', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11']]
>>> for i in one:
        one.remove(i)
>>> one
[['red', 'rfg', 'erg', '234', '23423434234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
['red', 'gertus', 'gengie', '234', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
['red', 'sdf', 'sdf', '23', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11']]
```

Why did the remove() only remove one set of the duplicates? Should I do something different because there are duplicates?

Comment: Do you want to remove the duplicates or everything?

Comment: If you want to remove everything `one = []` is enough..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question mentions duplicates, which means your question is a bit ambiguous regarding what you are actually looking for. I think you mean to remove all of the elements of the list BECAUSE they are duplicates. (If you really, truly meant to start with a brand new empty list, see @Óscar López's answer.)

If you simply want to remove duplicates, consider the following. You are changing the list as you iterate through it, which means that you won't be able to remove all the elements you have in your list here. Try this instead:

```
>>> one = [['red', 'rfg', 'erg', '234', '23423434234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
['red', 'gertus', 'gengie', '234', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
['red', 'sdf', 'sdf', '23', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
['red', 'rfg', 'erg', '234', '23423434234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
['red', 'gertus', 'gengie', '234', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11'],
['red', 'sdf', 'sdf', '23', '234234234234', 'F', '2014-01-11']]
>>> [i for i in one if one.count(i) < 2]
[]
```

Look at it like this:

```
t = [1, 2, 3, 4]
for i in t:
    t.remove(i)

[1, 2, 3, 4]
 ^
remove t[0], now t == [2, 3, 4]

[2, 3, 4]
    ^
remove t[1], now t == [2, 4]

There is no t[2], so we are done.
```

`[i for i in one if one.count(i) < 2]` is a [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). A list comprehension creates a new list rather than modifying the first list in-place. In essence, for your purposes here, that means you don't need to worry about the list changing shape as you try to modify it.

Comment: Sorry for the question but I am new to python. Why are you using the [] first before the for loop starts?

Comment: @Pythonist See the link to list comprehensions above.

Comment: Thank you! That link is great, always more new things to learn.

Comment: Sorry to bother, but that page on list comprehension only does append, it doesn't have any examples to remove. How would you do that?

Comment: @Pythonist Hey, no worries. I updated the answer above. This is one way to remove duplicates: [i for i in one if one.count(i) > 1]

Comment: Ok, but how would you write it to remove everything?

Comment: @Pythonist Whoops, one sec. I put greater than instead of less than.

Comment: @Pythonist Sorry about that. I updated the answer above and included the output from my interpreter. It should work just fine now.

Answer (score 2):

And how about this?

```
one = []
```

That's a lot simpler...

Comment: ...but not the same. `one.clear()` is probably what you're after.